# Using paginate with more than one query output in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I have outputs from 5 different queries, how can I use paginate with them.
As per Laravel docs, I should replace `->get` with `->paginate` and in the blade use something like `{{ $array->links() }}`.
This works fine with one query. How can I implement this with 5 queries ?
What would be the technical solution for this ?

Comment: Opinion based questions are against SO Guidelines

Comment: Question editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` is the output of your 1st query. Simple assign your 5 queries to a different variable and return them in your view.

You can treat them as nested arrays of a parent array like you said, it will work.

Pagination links are nothing more than another array field, outside of your data array so the principals that you would use for a normal array apply also here.

Comment: Do you mean using array_merge() to merge all arrays ? I think it requires all arrays to be the same length, correct ?

Comment: You can always just nest them in an array using `$newArray[] = $array1` for example. You don't need  any "strict merge" over there you just want to return your 5 array paginated data in your view